# How i can run normal voice recognition app in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, speech-recognition

How i can run normal voice recognition app in android emulator ? This app just convert the voice to text. when i try to run this app in my android emulator it gives "Recognizer not present" error message. I read several blog & forum but i can not find any suitable solution. This problem gives me a lot of pain. How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  are not able to record sound in emulator because the android emulator doesn’t support it yet. This code should only work on the phone